# stm32f407 discovery board + expansion board ethernet example

Tags: stm32, stm32f4discovery

would someone be good enough to provide STCubeMX project that is able to run ethernet example with stm32f407 discovery board + expansion board.

Big tnx!

Comment: I think there is working example for ethernet - without need ot Cube. But it is important which IDE/Compiler you have.

Comment: I am in need of CubeMx project for debugging purpose.